# Creating function for visualization using pandas plot() for multiple features in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization

I am trying to create a function to get plot for individual feature. I tried to create a new function when am applying it i ran into error. if any one help me on this will be very help full. kindly have a look into this.

Dataset Link - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dphi-official/Datasets/master/credit_risk/training_set_labels.csv

### Code -

```
cat_variable = ['checking_status', 'credit_history', 'purpose', 'saving_status', 'employment', 'personal_status', 'other_parties', 'property_magnitude', 'other_payment_plans', 'housing', 'job', 'own_telephone']

target = ['class']

def cat_visual(cat_variable):
        feature = cat_variable
        feature.value_counts().plot.bar(figsize = (8, 6))
        return cat_variable`
```

when i run following code it giving error-

```
cat_visual([0])
```

Error -

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2753df82ff33> in <module>
----> 1 cat_visual([0])

<ipython-input-21-5502069034a6> in cat_visual(cat_variable)
      4 def cat_visual(cat_variable):
      5         feature = cat_variable
----> 6         feature.value_counts().plot.bar(figsize = (8, 6))
      7         return cat_variable

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

I want when I give feature in my customize function, i can have bar plot.

If anyone help me on this i will be very glad & thankful to everyone who help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, value_counts() method needs to be used on a Series object (for eg. a dataframe column). See documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Also, when you call cat_visual([0]), you aren't specifying what is denoted by 0. Assuming you want to display a feature from the cat_variable list, you should pass cat_variable[0] as the argument. If you just need to display a plot, you don't need to return anything from the function.

The following code snippet would solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dphi-official/Datasets/master/credit_risk/training_set_labels.csv')
cat_variable = ['checking_status', 'credit_history', 'purpose', 'saving_status', 'employment', 'personal_status', 'other_parties', 'property_magnitude', 'other_payment_plans', 'housing', 'job', 'own_telephone']

target = ['class']

def cat_visual(cat_variable):
    feature = cat_variable
    df[feature].value_counts().plot.bar(figsize = (8, 6))

cat_visual(cat_variable[0])
```

[image: Here is the output:]

Comment: Thanks Ishwar Venugopal Sir